# On what game versions the "Missing Purple Nines" bug can be found?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-iii

From the [Glitches in Grand Theft Auto III](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Glitches_in_GTA_III#Missing_Purple_Nines) page on GTA Wiki:

> If the player starts a new game on a memory card with the mission Rumble completed, the Purple Nines, who are wiped out in that mission, will not spawn in the new game due to a programming oversight. This will make it impossible to complete Uzi Money and subsequent D-Ice missions, as killing Purple Nines gang members is the objective of these missions.

In what game versions does this happens? (Platform and Version/Product Code if possible)

Comment: The fact that it says memory card makes me think the PS2 version, since all other platforms that the game was originally for do not have memory cards (original Xbox being the other console).

Comment: Yeah, the mention of "memory card" makes me think about the PS2 version, but there are 11 different PS2 releases of the game (12 if you count the PS4 version that is a custom version of a PS2 US release). Also I believe that is possible with day one PC US releases, but I have not tried.